# Group enum members?

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to be able to determine if an enum value belongs to a certain group. See the pseudo example:

```
[Flags]
public enum Animals
{
  Dog = 1,
  Cat = 2,
  WildAnimal = Dog | Cat,
  Fly = 4,
  Bee = 8,
  Insect = Fly | Bee
}

public static bool IsInsect(Animals animals)
{
  return Animals.Insect.Qualifies(animals);
}

public static bool Qualifies(this Animals groupName, Animals value)
{
  //Is there a bitwise operation for it?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `HasFlag` method on enum.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((groupName & value) != 0)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "and" and check for common bits:

```
return (groupName & value) > 0;
```

Comment: does not compile because it first calculates the result of `value > 0` and then applies the bitwise and, which is impossible.

Comment: this makes me curious, though. What's the correct implementation: `>0` or `!=0`?

Comment: Since the enum by default has a signed base type, the "correct" implementation would be !=. However, negative flag values doesn't make much sense. So in practice I would say that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Place a description attribute or a custom attribute off of each individual enum and then get that information from reflection. I provide an example of such usage with enums on my blog entitled:

[C# Using Extended Attribute Information on Objects](http://omegacoder.com/?p=28)

HTH